# SQL subselect to jpql

Tags: sql, jpa, jpql

How can i write this sql in jpql syntax?

```
SELECT
SUM(t1.preise)
FROM
 (
SELECT
  preise
FROM
  `preistabelle`
ORDER BY
  `pid` DESC
LIMIT
  6  
 ) as t1
```

It is a subselect. I get an error if i try something like this:

SELECT sum(t1.preise) FROM (SELECT a.totalGRP FROM preise a) as t1

Error is unexpected token "("

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. It's not supported by JPQL.